# Proving an alternating infinite series to be divergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I am trying to prove $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-4)^{3n}}{5^{n-1}}$$ is a divergent series. I know that it increases as the series progresses regardless of sign, so it must be divergent, but im not sure how to prove it.

Usually with an alternating infinite series as long as the term not involving the minus doesnt tend to zero then it is easy to prove, however in this, that term is $$\frac{1}{5^n-1}$$ (I think), so it makes it a little harder, maybe i'm taking the wrong appraoch to this,  any help?

Comment: Hint: what is $\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$? Or, write the summand with an explicit form of $ar^n$, to make it look clearly like a geometric series, then check that $|r|\ge 1$ (which implies that the geometric series is divergent, e.g. since the $n$-th term will not tend to $0$ as $n\to\infty$).

Answer (score 2):

Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert\frac{(-4)^{3n}}{5^{n-1}}\right\rvert=\infty$, you don't have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(-4)^{3n}}{5^{n-1}}=0$, and therefore the series diverges.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\dfrac{(-4)^{3n}}{5^{n-1}}=5\left(\dfrac{-64}5\right)^n$$

Use [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Proof_of_convergence)

Comment: Wow that makes it alot easier! Thank you! Sorry I am new to the topic.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Use the [d'alembert Ratio Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test).